# Simple VowJS Test Callback Hangs - I can't see why?

Tags: node.js

I'm really sorry to paste code like this. I'm completely dumbfounded here - can anybody tell me why this hangs? Paste the following in `test.js` then run `node test.js` (with vows@0.8.1) and it'll hang.

Can anybody tell me why?

```
var vows = require('vows');
var assert = require('assert');

function foo(cb) {
    console.log("Calling...");
    cb("test");
    console.log("Called.");
}

vows.describe('Make Vow hang').addBatch({
    'return a value': {
        topic: function () {
            return "bar";
        },

        'this is': {
            'executed fine': function (topic) {
                assert.equal(topic, "bar");
            }
        }
    },
    'call a function': {
        topic: function () {
            foo(this.callback);
        },

        'this is': {
            'never executed': function (err, topic) {
                console.log('This wont get logged.');
                assert.equal(false, true);
            }
        }
    }
}).run();
```

The output shows one successful test (the final period) then it hangs:

```
Calling...
Called.
·
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `call a function` topic have a return statement?

Comment: @DarekKay Nah, that's a feature of VowJS. You can pass a callback method to test async methods which require one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't hang on my vows@0.8.1 but it got `callback not fired` error.

Vows follows Node.js async pattern, `callback(err, arg0, ..., argN)`. That means the first argument passed in the callback function is expected to be an `Error` object.

If you modify your function `foo` by removing `"test"` from the callback, it will work.

```
function foo(cb) {
    console.log("Calling...");
    cb();
    console.log("Called.");
}
```

The result of Vows after the modification:

```
Calling...
Called.
This wont get logged.
✗·

    call a function this is
      ✗ never executed
        » expected true,
        got      false (==)
  ✗ Broken » 1 honored ∙ 1 broken (0.011s)
```

Comment: Sure, although removing the arg doesn't help test any of `foo(cb)`'s output ... in any case, I tried `cb(false, "test")` which worked so long as I don't have an `err` arg in my test, in contrast to their [docs](http://vowsjs.org/) ... although now I'm struggling to get the `--spec` reporter working... to be honest, this is too much friction and I'm going to use Mocha and promises. Thanks for the answer though :)